# Two sample T-Test in SAS

Tags: sas, stat

I am trying to run a campaign analysis. I have two campaigns A and B and I have their sample size and response rates.

```
Data structure:

Campaign_Name    Response_Flag
   A                 0
   A                 1
   A                 1
   B                 1
   B                 0
```

I have summarized to get a response rate and sample size

```
Campaign_name     Sample_size   Response Rate
   A                 6500          0.7%
   B                 3600          1.2%
```

I want to see if the two campaigns are statistically similar or different .

Please help !!

Thanks

Comment: Looks more like a case for a test of difference between two proportions (googling those terms should get you the answer). Optionally check on Cross Validated.